# Are Blindness and Deafness learned as separate spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, spells

In Pathfinder and 3.5e D&D, are Blindness/Deafness separate spells, by which I mean do you need to learn each spell individually to cast them or does learning one mean you can cast the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No.

Unlike *detect evil*, et alia; *magic circle against evil*, et alia; and *protection from evil*, et alia; *blindness/deafness* is a singular spell which asks the caster to make a choice when casting as to which effect will attempt to manifest.

> [Blindness/Deafness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blindness-deafness/) (*PH*, p. 206)
>
> [...]
>
> You call upon the powers of unlife to render the subject blinded or deafened, **as you choose.**

Contrast this language and spell entry with *detect*, *protection* and *magic circle* spells, which not only have separate entries, but do not offer any option to choose to the caster. *Magic circle against chaos* is only ever protective against those creatures and effects spelled out in the description.

Finally, examining the entry for [*remove blindness/deafness*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-blindness-deafness/) (*PH,* p. 270) makes it clear that *blindness/deafness* is a singular spell, as the counterspell entry in *remove blindness/deafness* refers to *blindness/deafness* as a singular spell.